# How to select all from table based on username

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to ask how to select all from table based on username? I mean for example my user 1 insert his/her data and send to localhost and in status page will display their own data only. Below is my status page php.

```
<?php 
require_once('dbConnect.php');


//Creating sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";

//getting result 
 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//creating a blank array 
$result = array();

//looping through all the records fetched
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

//Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
array_push($result,array(
"id"=>$row['id'],
"username"=>$row['username'],
"name"=>$row['name']

));
}

//Displaying the array in json format 
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Use a `where` clause on the query. You should parameterize the query as well.

Comment: How individual user move on the status page? You should set some parameter to detect which user come to status page? If you set any parameter then use `where` clause

Comment: The insert page has view status button, user click it and it will display the data which inserted by them, but my one now display all the data inserted by different user.

Comment: IF you are using SQL it will be nice to read some docs.

Comment: I am using php and localhost, this query i use sql query and implement it in php file

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE username = 'john'"
```

This is assuming your table is actually named 'Table' as you have it above. Otherwise replace it with the actual table name.

If you have a variable for user name do this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE username = '" . $username . "'";
```

Comment: $username want declare before this line "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE username = '" . $username . "'";?

Comment: Yes, $username would have to be declared before that.

Comment: $username = $_POST['username']; declare this?

Comment: Yup, assuming you have an input on your form with `name="username"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WHERE` clause in the query like.

```
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE username = 'lun L'"
```

But this is not a good way to fetch data by user name. You should select users on `ID` base and ID should be unique. Because there are so many users who might have the same name.

```
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE youUniqueColName = '$uniqueVal'"
```

If unique column is `id` then use `id='$id'`

Comment: Yes, better to set with a query string.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE username = 'username'
```

Use this if you want a fixed SQL Query in your variable, or use;

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE username = '$username'
```

if you have an input that asks a username to display a specific username..